# Where and how to use new scope/context on a webserver running javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, webserver

I'm currently developing webserver in C# which using javascript as the server-sided language (using hte javascript.net library, port of v8 engine for .NET https://github.com/JavascriptNet/Javascript.Net).
Currently I have a this problem: When I'm parsing and than running a script from a file, the variables which created in the proccess stay exist forever, because I'm running all the scripts on the same javascript context. What should I do to prevent that? Create a different context for every request in webserver? I guess that's not the answer since it will be very uneffecient. And since I cannot create a scope in javascript simply by open and close brackets like i can do in C-like languages I dont know what to do. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can execute code in closures like `(function() { ... })();`. Anything inside this function's body will not be exposed to the global scope except global variables (i.e. `window.var1` or if you omit the `var` keyword).

Comment: I'm not sure I can do this because I acually parse the page, extract from it the server-sided code to a list, than I run the scripts on the list and inside the list there are the scripts for the outputs ( like when you do this line in php for example: <?php echo x ?> and it outputs the variable x to the html responde file). So I must exceute them in that order and when an output is encountered it outputs it to the file so I cant wrap that up in a single string and add what you said above.